# How to get the last inserted ID in several queries done with the same connection?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

I have a couple of mySQL queries inside a PHP script, that I put together inside a transaction.

I want to get the last inserted ID of each query, but it only works the first time, because the last inserted ID remains the same, (I guess it's because it's effectively treated as one big query, and there's just one connection).

These are my queries:

```
$conectarDB->beginTransaction();

$a = $conectarDB->prepare("  INSERT INTO usuarios SET  userEmail =?, userName =? WHERE userID=?  ");
$a->bindParam(1, $userEmail);
$a->bindParam(2, $userApellido);
$a->bindParam(3, $userID);
$a->execute();

$pago1 = $conectarDB->lastInsertId();

$b = $conectarDB->prepare("  INSERT INTO versionesUsuarios  SET userID=?, userEmail=?  ");
$b->bindParam(1, $userID);
$b->bindParam(2, $userEmail);
$b->execute();

$pago2 = $conectarDB->lastInsertId();

$conectarDB->commit();
```

How to solve this? How to get `$pago1` and `$pago2`

Comment: This should work fine, since you're calling for `lastInsertId` after the executes. If you do it after commit it would return `0`. Even with or without `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` Guessing they are the same IDs as they are different tables and coincidentally have the same ids.

Comment: You are however missing a parameter on your first INSERT. Needs `userID` so `$a->bindParam(3, $userID);`

Comment: Thanks! (I've corrected the missing parameter, thank you!)

Comment: Do you still have the issue? I can not reproduce. If so please add the table schemas. `show create table usuarios;` and `show create table versionesUsuarios;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try this after every executed query. I hope it's work.

```
$keys = $conectarDB->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
$arr = $keys->fetchColumn();
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this because commit executes all query at once. try to begin and commit in each insert query.

```
 $pago1 = $conectarDB->lastInsertId();
 $conectarDB->commit();
 $conectarDB->beginTransaction();
```

Comment: Shouldn't matter since execute is the submission to the database. The ID is still incremented, even when you rollback the transaction after executing and without committing.